# Should #define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK be necessary? c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I use `MinGW64` with `eclipse` to compile a `FreeGLUT` example program.
I get the following error.

```
11:55:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project OpenGL ****
```

Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-ID:\...\3rdPartyLibraries\freeglut\include" "-ID:\...\3rdPartyLibraries\freeglut\lib\x64" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o "src\LUtil.o" "..\src\LUtil.cpp" 
g++ "-LD:\...\3rdPartyLibraries\freeglut\lib\x64" -o OpenGL.exe "src\cPoint.o" "src\OpenGL.o" "src\LUtil.o" -lglu32 -lfreeglut_static -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 
src\LUtil.o: In function `glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK':
D:/.../3rdPartyLibraries/freeglut/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:620: undefined reference to`**imp**_glutInitWithExit'
src\LUtil.o: In function `glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK':
D:/.../3rdPartyLibraries/freeglut/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:622: undefined reference to`**imp**_glutCreateWindowWithExit'
src\LUtil.o: In function `glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK':
D:/.../3rdPartyLibraries/freeglut/include/GL/freeglut_std.h:624: undefined reference to`**imp**_glutCreateMenuWithExit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

So I searched the header and found in `freeglut_std.h`:

> /* Comment from glut.h of classic GLUT:
>
> Win32 has an annoying issue where there are multiple C run-time
>     libraries (CRTs).  If the executable is linked with a different CRT
>     from the GLUT DLL, the GLUT DLL will not share the same CRT static
>     data seen by the executable.  In particular, atexit callbacks registered
>     in the executable will not be called if GLUT calls its (different)
>     exit routine).  GLUT is typically built with the
>     "/MD" option (the CRT with multithreading DLL support), but the Visual
>     C++ linker default is "/ML" (the single threaded CRT).
>
> One workaround to this issue is requiring users to always link with
>     the same CRT as GLUT is compiled with.  That requires users supply a
>     non-standard option.  GLUT 3.7 has its own built-in workaround where
>     the executable's "exit" function pointer is covertly passed to GLUT.
>     GLUT then calls the executable's exit function pointer to ensure that
>     any "atexit" calls registered by the application are called if GLUT
>     needs to exit.
>
> Note that the __glut*WithExit routines should NEVER be called directly.
>     To avoid the atexit workaround, #define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK. */

I don't get the technical details, but there is obviously an option to disable it. Namely `#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK`.
When using this define the error message goes away and it compiles.

So the question that occurred to me is: "Is this what I'am supposed to do or is it just a bad way to fix something that should be fixed elsewhere?"

As I lack an informatics background I don't really understand the implications of this "exit problem" and the workaround. What I figured out is that the workaround is probably there for a very good reason, so it may not be wise to disable it.
So is setting the define the proper way to handle this error or is it just masking the effects of an issue that should be fixed somewhere else?

My question essentially boils down to: "Should I use #define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK or is there some other/better way of fixing this?"

Also if you could fill me in on the theoretical background on this one I'd be interested.